# ADFIND connection using SSL

Tags: ssl, certificate, edirectory

I'm using ADFIND to connect to a eDirectory data repository (similar to Active Directory) and I'm not able to connect using the "-ssl" option. This is the command I'm using in a .bat file:

`adfind -csv -csvq "" -csvdelim "|" -csvmvdelim ";" -b ou=apps,o=company -f -h <server-ip> -p 636 -ssl -t 600 -u <user account> -up <user password> CN description> output.csv`

The error I'm facing is: `Error 0x51 (81) - Server Down`

Which is not true, the server is running fine, once I can connect using Apache Directory Studio, for example.

The main doubt I have at this point is regarding the ssl configuration for ADFIND, I know that we must set the option `-ssl` but I'm not sure if I need to define the certificate path, or from where the ADFIND checks for the ssl certificate in the machine.

The eDirectory server does not accept simple bind and non-secure connection, so, I'm not able to connect to the 389 port as well.

Does anyone knows how to overcome this issue

Thanks in advance!